# My New Computer has HP BIOS Update problem

Tags: windows, updates, bios

I am havin a big problem from yester day . I bouth a new hp laptop yesterday. After I finish setup configuration , It asked me to restart the systom to setup update the system.. after that update the scree not worked more, but some light of the key bods were working... it like something was happening.. i wait a few hours . it was the same.
 after I pushed "windows" key with "B" together then start updatin again. but it is happening again and again the same thing . not startin windows.
HP BIOS Update

The system BIOS is being recovered. The recovery will take several minutes to complete.
Do not shut down your computer during the process.
Writing new BIOS Image.
Block ...../2048
i have attached the scree photos of the screen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpEto.jpg)